# How to assign levels to a factor variable

Tags: r, r-factor

I have a data set in R with a column yr_renovated that has either 0 or a integer (i.e 1998)for the year a house was renovated in. How would i create a factor variable with the levels yes and no for if the house was renovated or not.

```
head(House_Data$yr_renovated,n=20)
[1]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0 1998    0    0    0    0    0    0
```

I was thinking of something along of lines of

```
levels(renovated)[levels(renovated) <= 0] <- "no"
levels(renovated)[levels(renovated) > 0] <- "yes"
```

but i saw this used online and i dont know how exactly this works, also i realised that if i make a mistake in the assignment of levels lets say

```
levels(renovated)[levels(renovated) <= 0] <- "yes"
levels(renovated)[levels(renovated) > 0] <- "yes"
levels(renovated)[levels(renovated) <= 0] <- "no"
```

the last levels will not override the first one my only level will be yes, how would i remove that first wrongly assigned level?

```
no  no  no  no  no  no  no  no  no  no  no  no  yes no  no  no  no  no  no  no 
Levels: no yes
```

This is what the final answer should look like or if using table()

```
renovated
  no  yes 
5762  238
```

but sometimes it will give me this result

```
renovated
 Yes 
6000
```

Excuse my rookie knowledge of R, we haven't worked much on R during our statistics module in university so far

Comment: House_Data$Renovated <- ifelse(House_Data$yr_renovated==0, 'No', 'Yes)

Comment: This actually makes more sense to use than what i was trying but when i try to copy it into r it keeps returning + when i hit enter as if a bracket is missing

Comment: Sorry, put another single quote after the word 'yes'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using `factor` and assigning desired `labels`:

```r
yr_renovated <- c(0, 0, 1998, 0, 2010, 0)

renovated <- factor(yr_renovated == 0, labels=c("Yes", "No"))
table(renovated)

#> renovated
#> Yes  No 
#>   2   4
```